# Descriptive Statistics from Java ArrayList

Tags: java, google-app-engine, arraylist

I have ArrayList of `Profile` object. `Profile` have properties like `age`, `gender`, `country`, etc.

Are there any library in java which can give descriptive statistics easily like number of female profile, number of male profile, number of female profile from USA, and other complex report.

The environment used is Google App Engine.

Thanks

Comment: curious - were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 4):

You can use descriptive statistics in apache commons math e.g.

```
// Get a DescriptiveStatistics instance
DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();

// Add the data from the array
for( int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        stats.addValue(inputArray[i]);
}

// Compute some statistics
double mean = stats.getMean();
double std = stats.getStandardDeviation();
```

You will need to add the gender/country information into the descriptiveStatistics provided by commons math.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple library like [javascriptstats.com](http://javascriptstats.com)

It is specific to numerical statistics and has the following functions:

- Mean
- Median
- Mode
- Range
- Variance
- Standard Deviation

Cheers!